# AWS "Soon" message with Route 53, ALB and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have AWS Route 53 pointing to an Application Load Balancer which then forwards via a listener to an EC2 instance which is hosting a website (Microsoft IIS).

The strange thing is that sometimes then I refresh the page I see the correct webpage but other times I see the following message - A simple white screen with the text "Soon" on it.

[image: "Soon" message]

I only have a single EC2 instance running at this stage as well.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark. We cannot help if you don't show us the code which produces your "Soon" message. If you run a single instance, it does sound like a race condition within your application

Comment: Hi OlegI, it's a strange issue as it happens on multiple websites all with different code bases so I do not believe it is an actual code issue - thanks :)